# JS Calculator, results not showing up as intended?

Tags: javascript

Still learning JavaScript and I can't seem to figure out why my firstInput is doubling after doing a second number. Example, '1+' shows fine in the results screen, but when I click the secondInput to '2' hoping it comes out to 1+2, it instead shows me 112+2. Tried putting it into a stored input after making first input but still can't figure this out. Here is my code

https://codepen.io/Kaytin143/pen/bGRjQqx

```js
let firstInput = '';
let storedInput = '';
let secondInput = '';
let currentOp = '';
const results_div = document.querySelector('.screen')
const numberBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers')
numberBtns.forEach((numbers) => {
  numbers.addEventListener('click', () => {
    firstInput += numbers.value;
    storedInput += firstInput;
    results_div.innerHTML = firstInput;
    numberBtns.forEach((numbers) => {
      numbers.addEventListener('click', () => {
        secondInput += numbers.value;
        results_div.innerHTML = storedInput + currentOp + secondInput;
      })
    })
    //second Input
  })
})
// listeners for operators //
const operatorBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.c');

operatorBtns.forEach((operators) => {
  operators.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentOp += operators.value;
    results_div.innerHTML = firstInput + currentOp;
  })
})
```

Comment: Please, provide your `html` file as well so we can reproduce your code...

Comment: you initialise the `firstInput` as a `string`, therefore, when doing the plus operation, it will concat string instead of adding number

Comment: You're creating multiple instances of your listeners, and adding those listeners more than once to each button.

Comment: @Ricardo Added my codepen link in description

Comment: @kshetline just wanted to say thanks for pointing that out! It made alot more sense and I found a way around it.